# Spring AMQP advantages / disadvantages of using SimpleMessageListenerContainer over Receiving message from a queue

Tags: spring-amqp

I would like to know the advantages and disadvantages of using SimpleMessageListenerContainer over receiving a message manually using Spring AMQP. Another question is when we create SimpleMessageListenerContainer setting a queue, does the rabbitmq calls the listeneradaptor or does SimpleMessageListenerContainer keeps polling the queue to check for messages and calls  the registered adaptor when their is message.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your requirements; the listener container gives you an async (message-driven) approach. Otherwise, if you use the `RabbitTemplate`receive methods, you are polling the queue. The container does not poll the queue, the broker pushes messages to the container according to the prefetch settings (default 1) - if using ackmode AUTO.

Comment: Does it mean when we use SimpleMessageListenerContainer with queue, it registers its IP and listening port with Rabbit broker and broker pushes the message over network to SimpleMessageListenerContainer? If yes, how can I find the port for the listener container.

Comment: No; the container connects to the broker's port (as a client) and waits for data - the broker pushes messages to that client connection.